# php regex is not escaped

Tags: php, regex

what is a regex to find any text that has 'abc' but does not have a '\' before it. so it should match 'jfdgabc' but not 'asd\abc'. basically so its not escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
(?<!\\)abc
```

This is a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Basically this is saying: find me the string "abc" that is *not* preceded by a backslash.

The one problem with this is that if you want to allow escaping of backslashes. For example:

```
123\\abcdef
```

(ie the backslash is escaped) then it gets a little trickier.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'jfdg\abc';

var_dump(preg_match('#(?<!\\\)abc#', $str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the regex:

```
(?<!\\)abc
```

It matches a `abc` only if its not preceded by a `\`